# Java JSON serialization of an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, json

This should be simple.

I have an integer array that I want to encode in JSON formatting so I can pass it to a web service:

```
int[] myInts = new int[length-1];
myInts = {5, 6, 7, 1, 12, ..., 78}; 

JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
//now what?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i where you I'd create a JSONObject first and then create the JSONArray and use

```
myJsonArray.put(value);
```

and finally add the jsonarray to the JSONObject. I suppose this would work nice for a small set of numbers however if you want to pass a large set of integers there should be a more elegant way to do it than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myInts = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(myInts);
System.out.println(jArray.toString());
```

Comment: "The constructor JSONArray(int[]) is undefined" is what I got when I tried this.

Comment: [Javadoc for JSONArray(java.lang.Object array)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object)). Which JSON library are you using?